# Euler's totient function equation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I am having trouble with equation of type:

φ(n) = a, where a is positive integer and n is an integer

I need to find n, since I need to find all numbers n I was thinking about some modular arithmetic relation but didn't come with anything suitable for problem. What is valid mathematical approach for this problem and how all n can be found?
Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, didnt find the question while searching! Thanks